# Front- end image upload to file location and then retrieve image

Tags: php, html, wordpress, file-upload

How can a front-end uploaded image (via file-upload) be saved to the back- end (I'm using Wordpress, so a file location somewhere in wp-content), for the image to then be retrieved on another page so it can be viewed?

So far I attempted to use the following code, which has been unsuccessful. Here is the file upload on one page:

```
<input name="usp-files[]" type="file" maxlength="255" data-required="false" placeholder="File(s)" class="usp-input usp-input-files select-file multiple" multiple="multiple" id="usp-multiple-files" />
<input name="usp-file-limit" class="usp-file-limit" value="20" type="hidden" />
<input name="usp-file-count" class="usp-file-count" value="1" type="hidden" />
```

And then this code on another page to retrieve the image that was previously uploaded from the back- end file location:

```
foreach ($_FILES["usp-files"] as $file) {
echo '<input name="usp-files[]" value="'.$file["usp-files"]["tmp_name"].'" type="hidden"  />';
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the image was correctly uploaded?

Comment: @Phiter Fernandes To be honest, I'm not sure. I don't know how to set the destination where the image will be uploaded to. In terms of the actual button's functionality, when clicked a browse box will come up so in that respect it works fine. Once i've figured out how to save it to a set destination, then i'll need to be able to retrieve it.

Comment: https://tommcfarlin.com/upload-files-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear, You want to offer user possibility to upload multiple files and after that redirect him to page, where he can see these files, am I correct?

First things first, I cannot see form tag, make sure that You included **enctype="multipart/form-data"** attribute, whenever You want to work with files this is needed (than method has to be set to POST and also action where POST request will be sent).

Here is example how html code should look like:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="usp-files[]" multiple="multiple">
    <input type="submit" value="send files">
</form>
```

After that data are sent to test.php file. You can access them using $_FILES variable ([take a look how this array looks like](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)).

The problem is that You have inside $_FILES['usp-files'] - 5 arrays (name, type, tmp_name, error and size), which contains information of files You sent (again in array). This is why You cannot use foreach like that. In this case You are just accessing tmp_name. That makes it easier, take a look on example below:

```
foreach ($_FILES['usp-files']['tmp_name'] as $fileName) {
    echo '<input name="usp-files[]" value="'.$fileName.'" type="hidden"  />';
}
```

This is probably thing You wanted to show us in Your example. Unfortunately for me it does not work. It probably depends on configuration, temporary files are deleted almost immediately. To solve it I took these temp files and move them to my folder with their original name. After that I can access them. Again take a look on our example:

```
/* first set your directory where files will be moved */
$target_dir = "uploads/";

/*
    I used here for because I am going to work with indexes and it is more comfortable for me 
    pay attention on condition, I used array which contains name of all files uploaded (maybe there is
    some function to count FILES but never heard of that)
 */
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['usp-files']['name']); $i++) {
    /* This is path where file will be stored (my directory + file name) */
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["usp-files"]["name"][$i]);

    /* This is function which will move temp file (copy it) to directory I selected */
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["usp-files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file);

    /* After that you can print out that input with Your new path */
    echo '<input name="usp-files[]" value="'.$target_file.'" type="hidden"  />';
}
```

One more thing that may help You, I was testing this on software called WAMP. And there was disabled to upload multiple files. If You are using this either try to edit php.ini file (You can access it in system tray) and check those values:

```
file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

For me second and third was missing, I added them and it worked.

Okey, I hope I helped You hopefully You will solve it out :D

P.S.: Sorry everyone for grammar mistakes... Still learning English :D